# Difference between int.maxvalue and int.minvalue?

Tags: c#, int

i was wondering if you could help me explain one thing.
I want to know why i cant save the difference between int.maxvalue and int.minvalue into a variable of type long.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = int.MaxValue;
    int b = int.MinValue;

    long c = a - b;

    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.WriteLine(b);
    Console.WriteLine(c);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Why do i get a result of -1, and in this case:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    long a = int.MaxValue - int.MinValue;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Why do I get:

> Error CS0220 The operation overflows at compile time in checked mode.

I am puzzled because number of type long should easily store the difference between int.max and int.min?

Comment: You *first*, in the `int` domain, calculate `MaxValue` - `MinValue`. You *then* assign that result to a `long` variable called `c`. By that point, any constraints relating to working with `int`s have already taken effect. I.e. **expressions** don't have arbitrary precision.

Comment: The first case gives no error because by default, calculations are done in `unchecked` mode. There's an overflow, but you don't see it -- wrap it in `checked` to see it blow up. For compile time evaluation, the rules are different. (The solution in either case is to cast one of the parts to `long` before the subtraction, but that's covered in the duplicate.)